# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request' - YouTube data API

Tags: python, google-api, data-analysis, youtube-data-api

YouTube data API:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'

I am trying to fetch data from YouTube data API v3 in Python but I am getting:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'

Here is the code:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


youtube = build("youtube", "v3", api_key)

def get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_id):
    request = youtube.channels().list(
           part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
           forUsername=channel_id
    )
    response = request.execute()
    return response

get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_id)
```

getting this

```
AttributeError

Cell In [14], line 1
----> 1 get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_id)

Cell In [13], line 6, in get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_id)
      1 def get_channel_stats(youtube, channel_id):
      2     request = youtube.channels().list(
      3            part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
      4            forUsername=channel_id
      5     )
----> 6     response = request.execute()
      7     return response

File c:\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py:130, in positional.<locals>.positional_decorator.<locals>.positional_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    128     elif positional_parameters_enforcement == POSITIONAL_WARNING:
    129         logger.warning(message)
--> 130 return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Python310\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py:923, in HttpRequest.execute(self, http, num_retries)
    920     self.headers["content-length"] = str(len(self.body))
    922 # Handle retries for server-side errors.
--> 923 resp, content = _retry_request(
    924     http,
    925     num_retries,
...
--> 191     resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
    192 # Retry on SSL errors and socket timeout errors.
    193 except _ssl_SSLError as ssl_error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'request'
```

I installed googleapiclient from pip I can't find the proper solution related to YouTube data API.

Comment: you should not display your api_key.

Comment: Spelling? Your variable is named "reques"

Comment: I corrected that but the error is showing at request.execute()

Comment: which `googleapiclient ` version you are using ?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535140/google-api-python-client-doesnt-work-with-developer-key

Comment: I am using version 2.65